# Getting x and Y coordinates from images

Tags: android, view

There is any function in android allow to get x and y of each point displayed in screen,for instance,view that display curve,this curve is set of points which each of them has cordinates x and y,so haw we can get this cordiantes from this view.Thank you for your repley in advance.

Comment: The best way to ask is by showing what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Bitmap object you may do that by getPixel()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel(int, int)

To get coordinates of that curve you have to iterate through the whole bitmap